# Toggle panel with "space" input key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good morning everyone.
I must finish a little project for next month in unity.
This project is a remestered Angry Bird.
I want to create a code which allow to display and hide a panel everytime when I use Space touch on my keyboard.
Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class RadialMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] RadialMenuItems;
    public AudioSource AudSourc;
    public AudioClip MovementClip;
    public AudioClip UseClip;
    public GameObject radialMenu;
    Vector2 NormalizedMPose;
    float AngleOfMouse;
    int SelectedItem;
 
    int PrevItemID=5;
 
    void Update()
    {
        if ((radialMenu.activeSelf == true) && Input.GetKey("space"))
            radialMenu.SetActive(false);
 
        else if((radialMenu.activeSelf == false) && Input.GetKey("space"))
            radialMenu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I can hide the panel when I click in Space button for the first time but I can't display it again with the button.
I'm actually stuck on it and I can't finish my project.
Any help please
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the GameObject is disabled the Update method is not executed executed anymore.

A solution would be to disable a child GameObject, so that the Update method is executed.